# Maven Integration for Eclipse JDK Warning

Tags: eclipse, maven, java

I've installed Maven from the `Marketplace`, and I'm trying to create a new `Maven Project` in Eclipse

And this what I get when I create a new Project

[image]

How can I fix this JDK & JREs warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in `eclipse.ini` (a file next to the eclipse executable) add the full path to the java/javaw executable in your JDK:

on *x systems (probably including MacOS):

```
-vm
/path/to/jdk/bin/java
```

on Win*:

```
-vm
C:/path/to/jdk/bin/javaw.exe
```

or
    -vm
    C:\path\to\jdk\bin\javaw.exe

Make sure the `-vm` parameter comes before any `-vmargs`!

Comment: excellent, dude. wish I could give more upvotes. saved me at least an hour of googling and a million eclipse restarts :-)

Comment: A minor detail: "-vm" and "C:/path/to/jdk/bin/javaw.exe" should be in differents consecutive lines (ie, new line character).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a default JDK to the Installed Jres. Just install a JDK in the System click on the Link "Installed JREs" and add the folder where you installed the JDK to the paths. That's it.

Comment: Nope, this won't help. Maven requires that eclipse be *launched* using a JDK.

Comment: Im pretty sure it does. Never changed anything on the default settings of eclipse.

Comment: if it does, then your JDK comes before any JREs in your PATH env var. for most installations this is not the case. I know what I'm talking about, I used to provide Maven support for 60+ developers that used Eclipse and this was one of the major issues that I had to solve numerous times.

Comment: @Sean: i tested it on my local environment. You get this error also while having a valid -vm parameter and not having a valid JDK entry in "Installed JREs"

Comment: ok, perhaps the installed JDK is *also* required, which makes perfect sense. +1 for that